# Discordjs and commando

Tags: discord.js, commando

I'm using the commando library for discord js.

I need my bot to perform certain checks if the message is not a command. How can I go about achieving this with Commando?
Can I add an on Message listener?

Answer (score 0):

Commando is just a command handler and doesn't affect your event listeners. Yes you can declare on message events, And commando has in-built feature that if a message send with bot's prefix is not a command, replies with a custom message.